# What are we doing for National Novel Writing Month this year?

Tags: discussion, nanowrimo

November is National Novel Writing Month (NaNoWriMo). In the past, we've encouraged NaNo specific questions and provided chat room support for writers. Are we doing that again this year?

Comment: Perhaps we can do some scheduled NaNoWriMo chats?

Comment: Considering that NaNoWriMo encourages you to write every day of the month, perhaps there could be some kind of community-led question relevant to novel writing posted daily in order to encourage daily participation?

Comment: @Mike.C.Ford Trouble with that is it detracts from writing time.

Comment: If you already write every day of every month, barring injury or severe illness, then what should you do differently?

Answer (score 5):

How about a community short story?

Someone starts it running with an enigmatic sentence, maybe with a character limit (100) per person and this has to be finished till the end on the event. Best line gets a prize kind of thing.

I remember doing this in school as a creative writing exercise and it was extremely useful to help us think outside the box.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to get people who are already writing a bunch to write more and unrelated story.

Comment: One line??? If people have time to comment here and leave often looong comments, writing one line is not that unfeasible.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox You may be right, but let's try it anyway.

Comment: It would be an interesting idea, but then there's the problem with some people who intentionally mess up the story and throw things off track.  I remember doing this at school with a prompt, and it turned out very badly.  (I'm not saying that it's a bad idea, but feel free to go ahead)