# NaNoWriMo participants

Tags: discussion, nanowrimo

I decided to enter into the NaNoWriMo! If anyone here has entered into it, let's get support for each other going! Maybe we can exchange ID's or talk about struggles on this thread. Apologies if this is not the right area for this.

Comment: Great! Related: https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1372/26

Answer (score 6):

I'm in. I have this idea popping in my idea since ages, I'll be trying to give it a shape.

2000 words a day seems really ambitious, tho.

Comment: Only way to know is try. You sure won't do it if you don't (try) ^_^

Comment: Yes, that's why I am starting now, cause I work 9 hours a day (not including travel) and it will be a struggle to reach that mark. In the end I will be happy even if I don't make it. I just want to do something that can help see if I am motivated or not enough to actually see this through.

Comment: If you have created your profile, let me know I will add you as a buddy.

Answer (score 4):

I'm entering.

It'll be good to try something new. Never tried to write a whole novel in a month.

Comment: I have never tried to write a novel at all so everything about this is new to me. Being that I work 9 hours a day, I started writing already. I want to make sure I meet the mark!

Comment: Make sure you keep a notepad with you at all times. The best ideas can pop up at the most awkward moments... just don't tell your boss to wait a bit while you write something down ;) he he he.

Comment: Lol! I actually jot a lot of notes down in my phone and I also keep my icloud drive open on my work computer so I can type up any new inspirations. Been sacrificing my hour lunch break to work on it at work! We need to invent a machine that translates thoughts into notes. So many times i come up with something good as i am half asleep and drift off before i can muster the energy lol

Comment: Keep your note-taking device by your bedside. I tried to record mine on my smartphone :P but discovered I hate the sound of my own voice, so went back to paper and pen. But yes, having a way to take notes immediately is important. You don't want to go on with the nagging feeling that you've forgotten the best idea you ever had. But don't forget rest is also an important part of writing, you don't want to get burned-out.

Comment: For me this is a ton of fun. Bringing a world to life that has only resided in my head. To give this world life and a story has been amazing. But yes I have been making sure I rest plenty too! Last night i had a good idea to change a riddle i wrote for my story, but forgot to write it down :/ when I went to remember today I forgot what it was :/ but I’m okay with that because I am happy with the way it currently is too. My biggest fear is making sure i have enough material to go another 60-60,000 words.  Currently at 10,000 (writing in hopes of a 3 part epic).

Comment: I'm not a trilogy person :p I'd like to know how others are capable of limiting themselves. 10 000 is amazing! I'm only at a little over 7 000. This is why I'm entering NaNoWriMo. Maybe I'll learn how to write more... objectivity?!

Comment: I am entering to prove to myself that I am dedicated in becoming a novelist. And I wouldn’t say it’s about limiting myself but rather planning out a long tale that can be broken into mini stories. I find that trilogies are beautiful in that they involve so much layer and subplot that it’s hard to limit the story to 3 books (lotr was originally 6 before he combined and chopped them down). Grats on 7000! That’s awesome too! I hope you find what you are looking for too

Comment: I think you are well on the way to prove that. 10 000 words is amazing for someone working 9h. I know well how it is like to get home tired, trying to get your brain away from the day's turmoil and focused on this thing that you enjoy, but are sometimes too tired to pursue. And I love trilogies too, but I **need** to limit myself! My mind is allover the place with stories about the universe that exists in there. To hard to pick one and focus on it. I think I'd like to try a *...logy* of sorts ;) if I am able to keep at it.

Comment: let me know what your ID is! I can add you as a buddy!

Comment: I'm ShieldedTulip in there :) not sure about my number.

Answer (score 4):

I'm participating too! :) It's my third attempt. I 'won' last year, but I started with too little of a plan and never really found the heartbeat of that story despite the goal being reached. This year I have more of a grasp on that, so I'm hoping to have something workable by the end!

Looking forward to suffering along with you guys!

Comment: Wow :o well done on the win! It's easy to suffer for something we enjoy ;) just imagine if we were trying to do  a math marathon lol

Comment: Maybe I can add you as a buddy! let me know what your ID is

Comment: @shieldedtulip Thanks! It was tough but I really enjoyed it in the end, and it has definitely helped increase my productivity. I'm a math nerd too, but don't think I could do that for a month :P

Comment: @ggiaquin I'm sudowoodo on there too!

Comment: Okay... not sure how to add people by user name ><

Answer (score 4):

This is gonna be my second attempt at NaNoWriMo. Last year there was a lot going on, I wasn't really enamoured with the characters I was writing, and I ran out of steam about a third of the way through. This year I have a brand-new story idea (though set in the same universe as an existing one), and my life is a lot more settled.

If anyone wants to add me, my username on the site should be "F1Krazy", same as it is here.

Comment: Yes! It will be hard! I work full time as a software developer so my time will be very limited when I can spend quality time. I hope though that I can still meet the goals!

Comment: Same here. I have my commutes to and from work, my lunch breaks, and of course, the weekends. I was just barely keeping pace last year, until I burnt out, so I'm confident I can do it.

Answer (score 4):

At pretty much the last minute, I decided to try NaNoWriMo. I'm doing it mainly to try to better understand a universe I've been working on over the past year or two. Normally, I worldbuild for the sake of worldbuilding, rather than for a story. In this case, though, I have the world developed quite a lot, but I still don't know if everything in it truly works, for lack of a better word. I figured that if I try writing a story set in this universe, it might give me a better feel for how I've fit things together.

I've already asked some questions about my world on [Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), and I bet some thoughts will drift onto some posts on Writers (I do need to improve my writing!). I'd like to keep my NaNoWriMo ID private (it's under my real name), but I'll try to edit this to talk about my progress.

Comment: Cool man looking forward to it!